Vite builds locally but fails in GitHub pages CI after updating node.js
Vite built fine locally and in the GitHub Pages CI.
I then upgraded Node from 18.17.0 -> 18.20.2, it builds fine locally but now it fails in the CI.
I specified 18.20.2 in package.json engine, deleted and regenerated my package.lock.json file and that did not fix the issue.
The error I get is:
> tsc && vite build

/home/runner/work/React-Portfolio/React-Portfolio/client/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:59
        throw new Error(
              ^

Error: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try `npm i` again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
    at requireWithFriendlyError (/home/runner/work/React-Portfolio/React-Portfolio/client/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:59:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/React-Portfolio/React-Portfolio/client/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:68:76)
    ... 3 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:203:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24) {
  [cause]: Error: Cannot find module '@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu'
  Require stack:
  - /home/runner/work/React-Portfolio/React-Portfolio/client/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js
      at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
      at requireWithFriendlyError (/home/runner/work/React-Portfolio/React-Portfolio/client/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:41:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/React-Portfolio/React-Portfolio/client/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:68:76)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [
      '/home/runner/work/React-Portfolio/React-Portfolio/client/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js'
    ]
  }
}

Node.js v18.20.2
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

The suggested fixes I see are to delete your package.lock.json file and node_modules folder and let them get regenerated from the build, however I dont know how to do this in the pipeline nor do I think they even exist to begin with.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

I was able to fix this by running npm update which then created a corrected package-lock.json file and the build was able to run successfully from there.
